# If I create a stopwatch object and remove the variable for it, is it still taking up memory ticking? (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

Or does some sort of garbage collection system remove it?

If not, how *do* I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch) doesn't implement the [`System.IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IDisposable) interface, suggesting that there are *no* resources that may have to be released in a timely fashion.

Indeed, when you look at the [reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs), you'll see that the [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) WinAPI function is only called when needed (there is no event-based mechnism): on starting, pausing / stopping, when accessing the `.Elapsed` property.

Therefore, there are no special measure you need to take - removing the variable will remove the reference to the stopwatch instance (that variable may not be the only reference), and once the instance is unreferenced, it will eventually be garbage-collected.